# Round BigDecimal to the nearest integral value

Tags: java, bigdecimal

How would I *CORRECTLY* round a BigDecimal to the nearest whole value?

For instance

```
1.2 --> 1

1.5 --> 2

1.6 --> 2.
```

I tried

```
BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(1.5);
System.out.println(val.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
```

But this still gives me 1. NOT 2 as anticipated.

Does anyone happen to know how to correctly do this?

Thanks

Comment: [Your exact code outputs 2 for me on ideone](http://ideone.com/AoQnQ), there must be something else that you are doing that's wrong.

Comment: Multiply your number by 10 to the power of the number of decimal places you carry before rounding as a test.  In your example, you'd multiply by 10.  This will show you what number you're using in setScale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(1.2);
    System.out.println(val.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    val = new BigDecimal(1.5);
    System.out.println(val.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    val = new BigDecimal(1.6);
    System.out.println(val.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

Result:

1

2

2

I don't see where is the problem

Comment: Sorry, never mind. The problem was coming from a different place.And yes, the method works just fine.